# Creating new R column with different number of rows to df

Tags: r

I want to add a new column to a df called alcohol

```
df$alcohol <- df %>% 
  filter(condition=='alcohol') %>% 
  select(drift)
```

However, as 'alcohol' was one of two conditions, this new column will have less values and so I receive the following error message:

**Error: replacement has 36 rows, data has 72**

Does anyone know how to get around this error message and add the new column with less values?

Comment: A data.frame consist **by definition** of `ncol` columns of **equal** length `nrow`. What should the resulting structure look like? You could use list of lists...

Comment: There may be a number of easier approaches to this. It would be very helpful to see your data and desired outcome. Can you use `dput` and provide sample of data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `ifelse` statement to mark the values that match your condition with some label of your choice, e.g., `alcohol`, and mark the remaining values as `NA`(or some other value):

**DATA**:

```
df <- data.frame(
  drinks = c("apple juice", "coke", "whiskey", "milk", "water")
)
```

**SOLUTION**:

```
df$alcohol <- ifelse(df$drinks=="whiskey", "alcohol", "NA")
```

**RESULT**:

```
df
       drinks alcohol
1 apple juice      NA
2        coke      NA
3     whiskey alcohol
4        milk      NA
5       water      NA
```